# Configure zsh syntax highlighting for bash-my-aws

Tags: zsh, amazon-web-services, oh-my-zsh, bash-alias, zsh-syntax-highlighting

I have been using zsh syntax highlighter from this [repo](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/tree/master) and it has been very great so far. Now, I discovered a repo called [bash-my-aws](https://github.com/bash-my-aws/bash-my-aws) which aliases my awscli commands to a more usable and compact commands. For example, typing **`buckets`** will be equivalent to **`aws s3 ls`** and will list all my s3 buckets. But however, the command **`buckets`** is not recognized by the zsh syntax highlighting. It does highlight it, but as a bright orange, i.e. it is a wrong or unknown command. All the `bash-my-aws` aliases are grouped into one folder ***(~/.bash-my-aws)***; is there any way I can use the syntax highlighting tool to recognize all the aliases recorded in that alias folder?